# задача с пользователями в bash scripts

Tags: bash

В общем не могу догнать что я не так делаю ) есть задачка написать скрипт .. может кто может помочь в данном вопросе?

##Напишите скрипт для создания пользователей по принципу PrefixNumber.

##Введите входной параметр Prefix из командной строки;

##Number - номер пользователей;

##Номера пользователей - входной параметр скрипта.

##Пользователи могут менять свой пароль.

##Начальный пароль совпадает с именем пользователя.

##Для каждого пользователя создается личная папка, соответствующая его имени.

##Каждая папка имеет права, позволяющие просматривать и изменять ее только данному пользователю

#Оставьте полный контроль администратору.

```
echo 'Введите нужноe имя для пользователей'
read name
username=`echo $name$1`
password=$username@4125
useradd -m $username
echo $password | passwd $username
sudo chmod a+rwx,g-rwx,o-rwx /home/$username
echo Вы создали пользователя $username и ваш пароль $password
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не могу конкретно понять правильно ли я делаю, ведь у меня выскакивает ошибка с вводом пароля ... или лучше вводить пароль через -p  и не мучать себя?